# How to reload a lightningchart?

Tags: lightningchart

Trying to reload a [lightningchart](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js/) by simply calling the following twice (simplified to be concise)

```
//'viz' points to an existing element in the DOM where the chart is bound to
lightningChart().ChartXY({container: 'viz' })
```

The first time around the chart renders fine.
The second time, I'm getting a WebGL error:

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: bindBuffer: object does not belong to this context
```

This is likely caused by a WebGL context that is not freed between invocations.
Problem is how to reset the chart (and thus the canvas and/or WebGL context) before rendering the chart again? I tried `chart.dispose()` but this doesn't seem to work

Any pointers?

Comment: We're unable to reproduce this issue on our end. When disposing the Chart for the first time, try making sure you're removing any reference that might be tied to the same WebGL context (from Chart side, it would be best to remove all references you might have cached before disposing the chart).

If there are any more details you can share about this, it would be greatly helpful with solving this :)

Answer (score 0):

I am pleased to inform you that the issue has been fixed in our LCJS release v2.0.3. You can try and test this with our latest LCJS release. Visit https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-installation/

Thank you and please do mark this an answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: Please add as comment instead.

Comment: I can't put it in the comment as I don't have the minimum reputation needed for that at moment.

Comment: Page is giving a 404, please update